# regex for capturing the values

Tags: javascript, java, regex, regex-lookarounds

need some help with nested double quotes regex,

I have the following string:

```
"abcd-1234\":"  :   value\":1234\":
```

and I want to capture the entire string and separate it out into key and value pair but I am not able to come with a proper regex.

Basically, I have the following string format -->

```
 "key" : "value"
```

and I want to find a proper regex for the string format.

I am able capture the key and value individually  with the following regex -->

```
((^[\"]).*\2(?![^:]))
```

But not able to get a proper regex for the entire string.

Please, can someone help me with the regex.

Comment: I don't believe that regular expressions are the right tool for this particular job.  Why do you think a regular expression is what you need?

Comment: Then what would be the best way to the key and value ? Because, I need to find a way to get the key. I can't use the split here, as the `:` can be repeated in the string.

Comment: Your string `"abcd-1234\":"  :   value\":1234\":` is not in the form `"key" : "value"`

Comment: the key/value can contain anything... like double quotes/ blackslashes.

Comment: If this is JSON, you could use a JSON parser.  If these strings not intended to conform to JSON rules, you might have to write your own parser which iterates through the string and identifies the correct `:` character to split on, and any unescaped quote marks.

Comment: `value\":1234\":` is not surrounded with `"` characters.

Comment: Not clear. In your input `"abcd-1234\":"  :   value\":1234\":`, what is the key (`abcd-1234\":`?) and value (`value\":1234\":`?). Also could you post an example with multiple key/values, and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following string: `"\\"` - That contains `\"` but is still a complete, valid string. You can't just 'ignore `\"` - you have to count backslashes.

`(?:[^"\\]|\\.)` will cover any 'in-the-string' character: Either a backslash followed by anything (. is anything), or any character at all, as long as it isn't either a backslash, or a quote. A string is a quote, followed by any amount of those, followed by a quote, thus, a regexp appears.

However, regexps probably aren't the right tool for the job. This looks like a part of a JSON formatted input; there are JSON parsers that do a much better job on this, covering far more cases.